Terraform HTTP provider handling lists in request_body
I have a use case, which I believe, is covered with the basic HTTP provider from Terraform, however I'm running in to what I think is just a formatting issue.
I am trying to POST a list of list values to a generic REST API with a couple of other required parameters. The working cURL for this looks like the below:
curl -k -u admin:pass https://url:port/working/uri -d 'field1=value1' -d 'field2=[[value2a], [value2b]]'

Trying a different end point to confirm what I know, I am happy with the format of the other fields, but after trying several permutations of what I expected Terraform to need, I've come up empty with the format for 'field2'.
   request_body = {
    field1: "value1", 
    field2: "[['value2a'], ['value2b']]"
    }

Can anyone shed some light on how I should format field2?

curl's -d option operates at a higher level of abstraction than the raw HTTP request, whereas http is lower-level and uses HTTP request concepts directly without much additional abstraction. To translate your curl command line to an equivalent data "http" block will therefore require understanding the abstraction that curl is providing.
The curl manual page has the following information on the -d option, which is a shorthand for --data:

      -d, --data <data>
              (HTTP MQTT) Sends the specified data in a POST request to
              the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when
              a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit
              button. This makes curl pass the data to the server using
              the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
              Compare to -F, --form.

              --data-raw is almost the same but does not have a special
              interpretation of the @ character. To post data purely
              binary, you should instead use the --data-binary option.
              To URL-encode the value of a form field you may use
              --data-urlencode.

              If any of these options is used more than once on the same
              command line, the data pieces specified are merged with a
              separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d
              skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that looks like
              'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.

              If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should
              be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want
              curl to read the data from stdin. Posting data from a file
              named 'foobar' would thus be done with -d, --data @foobar.
              When -d, --data is told to read from a file like that,
              carriage returns and newlines are stripped out. If you do
              not want the @ character to have a special interpretation
              use --data-raw instead.

              The data for this option is passed on to the server
              exactly as provided on the command line. curl does not
              convert, change or improve it. It is up to the user to
              provide the data in the correct form.


There's a lot here but the most important details are:

The presence of at least one -d option forces using the POST method to make the request.
The option also implicitly selects the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded for the request. The manual doesn't explicitly state that "content-type" is a request header, but I know that to be true based on prior knowledge of the HTTP protocol.
When multiple -d options are present, they are concatenated together with & delimiters to form the overall request body.

Your command line also uses the -u option to specify a username and password to send in the request. The command line doesn't specify which scheme to use to send this information, and so curl defaults to --basic, which uses the "Basic" scheme that passes the given credentials in a request header field named Authorization, base64 encoded.
After resolving all of their abstractions down to the raw HTTP concepts they are built from, the following data "http" block should achieve the same effect as your curl command line:
data "http" "example" {
  url    = "https://url:port/working/uri"
  method = "POST"

  request_headers = {
    "Authorization" = "Basic ${base64encode("admin:pass")}"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
  request_body = "field1=value1&field2=[[value2a], [value2b]]"
}

There are some important caveats here:

Because http is a data source, Terraform expects it to perform only a read operation. It is not appropriate to use this data source for changing the state of a remote object, because Terraform will make the configured request during its plan phase whenever possible.
You probably shouldn't hard-code the admin password in your Terraform configuration as I showed above.
I included the space character from your second -d argument exactly as you wrote it to match your curl command line, but it's more common for space characters to be encoded as %20 or + when using this encoding scheme. That doesn't appear to be necessary for your specific system, but I'm mentioning in case someone else finds this answer in future while working with a system that expects the data to be properly encoded.

